# kubuntu 13.10 how to remove firefox installer

Tags: firefox, kubuntu, uninstall, shortcuts

I installed kubuntu 13.10 and in the menu I saw a Firefox installer. when i click the installer muon discover shows firefox. 
I don't want Firefox as rekonq is pre-installed  so how can I remove the Firefox installer from menu.
[image: firefox shurtcut]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q: how can I remove the Firefox installer from menu.**

**A: Quick**

```
sudo apt-get purge kubuntu-firefox-installer
```

If you don't want to remove the package - You could edit the KDE menu with the KDE menu editor: http://docs.kde.org/development/en/kde-workspace/kmenuedit/index.html

**A: More information**

**kubuntu-desktop**

The metapackage: http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/kubuntu-desktop is recommending the package: kubuntu-firefox-installer

More of the metapackages: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages

**kubuntu-firefox-installer**

The package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/kubuntu-firefox-installer is adding the option to install the Firefox to the Kubuntu 13.10.

```
:~$ apt-cache show kubuntu-firefox-installer
Package: kubuntu-firefox-installer
Priority: extra
Section: universe/kde
...
Description: Mozilla Firefox installer for Kubuntu
 Enables easy installation of Mozilla Firefox on Kubuntu, via a graphical user
 interface and menu entry.
...
Origin: Ubuntu
Task: kubuntu-desktop, kubuntu-full, kubuntu-active-desktop, kubuntu-active-full
```

If you remove the kubuntu-firefox-installer then the menu entry will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove --purge firefox
```

As per your comments, firefox isn't installed.  Is this what you mean? Click:

1. KDE System Settings
2. Default Applications
3. Web Browser
4. Bubble in "In the Following Browser:"
5. type rekonq %u

See [Chapter 13 of the Rekonq handbook](http://docs.kde.org/development/en/extragear-network/rekonq/rekonq.pdf)

Comment: it didnt worked the installer is still there

Comment: Package 'firefox' is not installed, so not removed

Comment: firefox isn't installed was the result when i ran the command sudo apt-get remove --purge firefox

Comment: i dont want to change the default web app. i just want the shurtcut removed

Comment: If Firefox is removed, log out,  and log back in...

Comment: CTRL + ALT + T
kmenuedit
See the [handbook](http://docs.kde.org/development/en/kde-workspace/kmenuedit/index.html)